# Is a Wajsberg algebra a Heyting algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

More precisely, I'm interested to know if the implication of a Wajsberg algebra is "distributive" (in the sense that $x \to (y \to z) \leq (x \to y) \to (x \to z)$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

No. An (in)equality is true in all Wajsberg algebras if and only if it true in the standard Wajsberg algebra over the unit interval $[0, 1]$, where $x 
\rightarrow y = \min(1-x+y,1)$. Your inequality fails for $x = 0.5, y = 0.5, z = 0$.